# Applying formula to rows with same name field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have set up a formula in my workbook like the one in the answer to this q (formatted according to the third answer down as that met my needs): [Highlight Rows in Sheet1 that match values in Sheet2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763755/highlight-rows-in-sheet1-that-match-values-in-sheet2)

I'm using it to mark rows that have a vendor code entry that can also be found in Sheet2. However, many of the rows of data in Sheet1 do not have a vendor code at all. I have done a lot of previous work in rationalizing the company name field and I want to also mark lines of data with the same company name as one in which there is a vendor code match.

e.g

```
|Company Name|  Vendor Code|    Vendor Code Match|
|------------|-------------|---------------------|
|ABC Company |          111|                  Yes|
|ABC Company |          N/A|                   No|
```

I would like row 2 to also have a vendor code match as it has the same company name as row 1.

Please go easy as I am very new to excel in general!
Thank you!

Comment: Please check the formula that you had put for vendor code. Also past the formula in your questions, so that SO can suggest right formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight the cells with conditional formatting, I would suggest

```
=AND($C2="No",MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$10=$A2)*ISNUMBER($B$2:$B$10),0))
```

with the ranges adjusted to the number of cells that you are dealing with.

If you wanted to use this as a stand-alone formula, it would have to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> with a check for an error on the MATCH

```
=AND($C2="No",ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$10=$A2)*ISNUMBER($B$2:$B$10),0)))
```

and you can also find the vendor code if you want to

```
=IF($C2="No",IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$10=$A2)*ISNUMBER($B$2:$B$10),0)),"Not found"),$B2)
```